# chrome extension indexof multiple value from get sync storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, indexof

Please help on this 1 week problem: I want to search/index the tab url from multiple value.
I want only to run extension on specific website base on users input url on options page. Thank you so much for the help
My manual code:

```
array = ["google", "yahoo", "facebook"];
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf("google") > -1 ) {
        "run extension code"
    }
    if (tab.url.indexOf("yahoo") > -1 ) {
        "run extension code"
    }
    if (tab.url.indexOf("facebook") > -1 ) {
        "run extension code"
    }});
});
```

Please help me to run this automatically and get sync from storage option.

Comment: I want only to run extension on specific website base on users input url on options page. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Use [event filtering](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#filtered).

Comment: @wOxxOm It is hard for me to understand. may I ask an example? Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to apply with your link example. But it makes me more confuse and my extension totally not running :(

Comment: Add the code you've just tried in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution on my problem. I solve it on my own research. Thank you so much for the help. This is exactly what I want.

```
var myurl = ["yahoo", "google", "bing"];
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    for (var i = 0, icount = myurl.length; i < icount; i++) {
        if (tab.url.indexOf(myurl[i]) > -1) {

            "run code to enable extension"

          break; // halt for loop
        }
      };
    }); 
});
```

Comment: this won't work as you expected. You are presuming that every time webNavigation is complicated in some tab, that tab must be the active one (if I'm getting this correctly). You already have URL in details from `webNavigation.onCompleted`, no need for tabs API (and that tabs method is deprecated btw.). If you want to use `webNavigation` API, you need to test `frameId  = 0`, and then url against your array

Comment: also, [as wooxom suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900430/chrome-extension-indexof-multiple-value-from-get-sync-storage#comment74835465_43900430) , the right way is to use filters

Comment: sorry but I don't really know how to use your suggestion filter. I am beginner here.